# Convert Adobe LiveCycle FormCalc summarization function to JavaScript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++, livecycle-designer

In Adobe LiveCycle Designer (xfa forms), the summarization function in FormCalc can be as follows:

```
Sum(Row[*].parts_value)
```

The above must be converted to JavaScript and must be as follows:

```
formCalcSum(this, "Row[*].partial_value");
```

where formCalcSum is new JavaScript function defined as follows:

```
function formCalcSum(prmNode, prmListStr) {
    var theList;
    var theSum=0;
    theList = prmNode.resolveNodes(prmListStr);
    if (theList) {
        for (var i=0; i < theList.length; i++) {
            theSum += theList.item(i).rawValue;
        }
    }
    return (theSum);
}
```

Can we write regex to achieve the above conversion using find/replace in Notepad++ for example?

(Note: the question was modified to simplify the required change and regex.)